# Calculate cumulative sums of certain values

Tags: r

Assume you have a data frame like this:

```
df <- data.frame(Nums = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10), Cum.sums = NA)
> df
   Nums Cum.sums
1     1       NA
2     2       NA
3     3       NA
4     4       NA
5     5       NA
6     6       NA
7     7       NA
8     8       NA
9     9       NA
10   10       NA
```

and you want an output like this:

```
   Nums Cum.sums
1     1        0
2     2        0
3     3        0
4     4        3
5     5        5
6     6        7
7     7        9
8     8       11
9     9       13
10   10       15
```

The 4. element of the column Cum.sum is the sum of 1 and 2, the 5. element of the Column Cum.sum is the sum of 2 and 3 and so on...
This means, I would like to build the cumulative sum of the first row and save it in the second row. However I don't want the normal cumulative sum but the sum of the element 2 rows above the current row plus the element 3 rows above the current row.

I allready tried to play a little bit around with the sum and cumsum function but I failed.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the `embed` function to create the appropriate lags, `rowSums` to sum, then lag appropriately (I used `head`).

```
df$Cum.sums[-(1:3)] <- head(rowSums(embed(df$Nums,2)),-2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any special function, just use normal vector operations (these solutions are all equivalent):

```
df$Cum.sums[-(1:3)] <- head(df$Nums, -3) + head(df$Nums[-1], -2)
```

or

```
with(df, Cum.sums[-(1:3)] <- head(Nums, -3) + head(Nums[-1], -2))
```

or

```
df$Cum.sums[-(1:3)] <- df$Nums[1:(nrow(df)-3)] + df$Nums[2:(nrow(df)-2)]
```

I believe the first 3 sums SHOULD be NA, not 0, but if you prefer zeroes, you can initialize the sums first:

```
df$Cum.sums <- 0
```

Comment: While this is a valid solution to this specific problem, it doesn't generalize nicely (e.g. if the cumulative sum was over 20 rows instead of 2).

Comment: @Joshua, you are right, I posted more general solution, but not very practical though. Your solution will probably be the best.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution, elegant and general, using matrix multiplication - and so very inefficient for large data. So it's not much practical, though a nice excercise:

```
len <- nrow(df)
sr <- 2 # number of rows to sum
lag <- 3 
mat <- matrix(
           head(c(
                 rep(0, lag * len), 
                 rep(rep(1:0, c(sr, len - sr + 1)), len)
               ), len * len), 
           nrow = 10, byrow = TRUE
       )
mat %*% df$Nums
```