# Running sums for every row of the previous 25 rows

Tags: r

I've been trying for a while now to produce a code that brings me a new vector of the sum of the 25 previous rows for an original vector.

So if we say I have a variable Y with 500 rows and I would like a running sum, in a new vector, which contains the sum of rows [1:25] then [2:26] for the length of Y,  such as this:

```
y<-1:500
runsum<-function(x){
   cumsum(x)-cumsum(x[26:length(x)])
}

new<-runsum(y)
```

I've tried using some different functions here and then even using the apply functions on top but none seem to produce the right answers....

Would anyone be able to help? I realise it's probably very easy for many of the community here but any help would be appreciated

Thanks

Comment: [possible duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10930810/cumulative-sum-for-n-rows)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This function calculates the sum of the 24 preceding values and the actual value:

```
 movsum <- function(x,n=25){filter(x,rep(1,n), sides=1)}
```

It is easy to adapt to sum only preceding values, if this is what you really want.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to Roland's answer you could use the zoo library

```
library ( zoo )
y <- 1:500
rollapply ( zoo ( y ), 25, sum )
```

HTH

Comment: can the 25 here by dynamic ? i.e. a vector of values

Answer (score 1):

I like Roland's answer better as it relies on a time series function and will probably be pretty quick. Since you mentioned you started going down the path of using `apply()` and friends, here's one approach to do that:

```
y<-1:500
#How many to sum at a time?
n <- 25
#Create a matrix of the appropriate start and end points
mat <- cbind(start = head(y, -(n-1)), end = tail(y, -(n-1)))
#Check output
rbind(head(mat,3), tail(mat,3))
#-----
       start end
           1  25
           2  26
           3  27
[474,]   474 498
[475,]   475 499
[476,]   476 500

#add together
apply(mat, 1, function(x) sum(y[x[1]]:y[x[2]]))

#Is it the same as Roland's answer after removing the NA values it returns?
all.equal(apply(mat, 1, function(x) sum(y[x[1]]:y[x[2]])),
          movsum(y)[-c(1:n-1)])
#-----
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Thanks - it helpful to see the apply function being used in a manner related to my work - I'll try this way out too so I at least know how it all works!